# PL/SQL select null value with other value

Tags: plsql

I have two columns, one is type and other is Id, i want to fetch all the records whose id is null for all the types except when type = 'Started', means when type is 'Started' then it should display the records without checking Id, in other types it will display only those records whose Id is null. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this where clause is just fine:

```
where type = 'Started' or (type <> 'Started' and id is null)
```

Also, this query belongs to SQL and not PL/SQL which is a procuedre language.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean something like:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'started' TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL ID, 'finished' TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 'finished' TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL ID, 'started' TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, 'started' TYPE FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 'progressing' TYPE FROM dual)
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  (ID IS NULL AND TYPE != 'started')
OR     TYPE = 'started'
ORDER BY TYPE, ID;

        ID TYPE
---------- -----------
           finished
         1 started
         3 started
           started
```